# How to compute the penalty for invariant risk minimization in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function

I am trying to implement the technique called "Invariant risk minimization," which adds a penalty term to the loss function in training machine learning models. The new penalty term's technical definition is the **squared gradient norm with respect to a constant classifier.** There is an implementation of this "penalty" function with PyTorch [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InvariantRiskMinimization/blob/master/code/colored_mnist/main.py).

I was wondering how I can implement this function in Tensorflow 2.

More specifically, I want to implement the function below, which is also in the code I shared its link.

```
  def penalty(logits, y):
    scale = torch.tensor(1.).cuda().requires_grad_()
    loss = mean_nll(logits * scale, y)
    grad = autograd.grad(loss, [scale], create_graph=True)[0]
    return torch.sum(grad**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a similar fashion :

```
def penalty(y_true, y_pred):
    scale = tf.constant(1.)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(scale)
        loss = tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred*scale, from_logits=True)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, [scale])[0]
    return tf.reduce_sum(grad**2)
```

Note that the order of the parameter logits and ground truth are reversed compared to the PyTorch version, to respect TensorFlow's convention.

To calculate a Gradient, you just need `tf.GradientTape`, you can read more in the guide : [Introduction to Gradients and Automatic Differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff?hl=en#computing_gradients)

---

Comparing that the 2 versions produces the same results :

PyTorch version:

```
>>> penalty(torch.tensor(1.),torch.tensor(0.))
tensor(0.5344, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)

>>> penalty(torch.tensor(1.),torch.tensor(1.))
tensor(0.0723, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

TensorFlow version:

```
>>> penalty([0.],[1.])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.53444666>

>>> penalty([1.],[1.])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0723295>
```